# Puzzling behaviour in IEqualityComparer<T>, breakpoint in the Equals() method is not hit

Tags: c#, linq

VS2013, .Net 4.5.2.

Given this code

```
            var opCollectionA = new List<Option>() 
            {
              ...some elements added here..
            };

            var opCollectionB = new List<Option>() 
            {
              ...some elements added here..
            };

            var InAandB = opCollectionA.Except(opCollectionB, new OptionComparer()).ToArray();
```

and this comparer class:

```
public class OptionComparer : EqualityComparer<Option>
{

    public override bool Equals(Option x, Option y)
    {
        //Check whether the objects are the same object. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        //Check whether the options have the same Entry value. 
        return x != null && y != null && x.OptionEntry.Equals(y.OptionEntry);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(Option obj)
    {
        //Get hash code for the OptionSection field if it is not null. 
        int hashOptionSection = obj.OptionSection == null ? 0 : obj.OptionSection.GetHashCode();

        //Get hash code for the OptionEntry field. 
        int hashOptionEntry = obj.OptionEntry.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code for the Option. 
        return hashOptionSection ^ hashOptionEntry;
    }
}
```

I am finding in Debug mode that GetHashcode is being called for each comparison but never Equals. Consequently my comparer doesn't give the desired outcome.

Can anyone explain this?

TIA.

Comment: That's the purpose of a `GetHashCode()`: if the hashcode of two instances is different, there is no need to call `Equals()` as different hashcodes already mean that the instances are different.

Comment: So if your `GetHashCode()` returns different results for instances that you actually want to be equal, your implementation is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hash code is used to speed up comparisons. So a `GetHashCode()` implementation should be faster than `Equals`.

`GetHashCode()` *must* return **equal** hash codes for **equal** objects (where "equal" means that `Equals()` would return `true`).

Since there are not enough `int` values to have a different hash code for each *different* object (for example strings), there will of course be *different* objects sharing the *same* hash code.

If `GetHashCode()` returns the *same* hash code for two objects, `Equals()` must be called to decide if they are really equal. But if `GetHashCode()` returns different values, you already know that these objects cannot be equal and don't have to call the - normally much more expensive - `Equals()` method.

**CONCLUSION:**

In your code you seem to expect two `Option`s to be equal if their `OptionEntry` is equal. So the easiest way to fix your problem is to change your `GetHashCode()` so that it simply returns the hash code of `OptionEntry`:

```
public override int GetHashCode(Option obj)
{
    return obj.OptionEntry.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That explains the problem.

Comment: Silly me, I was doing `obj.GetHashCode()`